# Load constant from string, as resolved in current scope

Tags: ruby, constants

Say I have the following structure:

```
module Library
  class DSL
    def met(str)
      # load `str` here; for this case, `MyApplication::MyClass`
    end
  end

  class Superclass
    extend DSL
  end
end


module MyApplication
  class MySubclass < Library::Superclass
    met 'MyClass'
  end

  class MyClass
  end
end
```

Inside `Library::DSL#met` I need to load constant `str`, which is provided as string. Obviously, it does not work if I simply do `Object.const_get(str)`.

I need somehow to fully resolve `str` in the context of the current scope (`MyApplication::MySubclass`); `str` would therefore be resolved as `MyApplication::MyClass`. I need to fully resolve this because later I need to use this constant outside this namespace.

Comment: And I guess `A.const_get('C')` is too specific?

Comment: Indeed. It's just a simplified example, the constant loading I am after is on a library level, so it does not know of `A`. Basically, it needs to resolve `C` in the current scope and then load it (i.e.: See that `C` is actually `A::C`, and then load it).

Comment: So you want to resolve the constant dynamically the way Ruby would resolve a literal `C`, i.e. it should take nesting and inheritance into account?

Comment: I have updated my question to better reflect the nature of my issue. @Stefan

Comment: Why don’t you pass the constant (i.e. the class) instead of its name?

Comment: Mainly because of loading it as late as possible.

Comment: So `MyClass` is actually located in yet another file?

Comment: Yes, `Library` is a gem, `MyApplication` is a user application.

Answer (score 2):

When resolving a constant, Ruby first checks the current nesting of modules and then the ancestors of the innermost module.

This can be replicated by traversing [`Module.nesting`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-c-nesting) and `Module.nesting.first.ancestors` (in that order). If a module defines the constant, we can get its value via `const_get`:

```
class A
  class B
    def met
      str = 'C'
      mods = Module.nesting
      mods.concat(mods.first.ancestors)
      mod = mods.find { |c| c.const_defined?(str, false) }
      mod.const_get(str)
    end
  end

  class C
  end
end

A::B.new.met #=> A::C
```

Comment: I see `Module.nesting` determines the nesting structurally, in the place it is called. However, my setup is a bit more complicated. `A::B` is actually included in another class (`class D; include A::B; end`), which is a base class for other classes (`class E < D; end`). Inside `E` I need to load this constant `C`, which is usually found in the same namespace as `E`, but not necessarily. So, bottomline, I am looking for the same thing `Module.nesting` does, but dynamically (perform the same lookup on the nesting it is actually called from). I'm sorry for this getting so confusing.

Comment: @linkyndy not sure if I can follow. Could you update your question accordingly?